# Can't find module after modifying PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a preexisting project, and want to find a new module by extending the `PYTHONPATH`. I added `~/code/serenity/api/serenity-api/serenity/python/src` to my `PYTHONPATH` env var, and when I print out `sys.path`, I see the path in the returned list. But when I try to import my file

```
from rbac.rbac import Rbac
```

I get no module found.

The full path to the file is

```
~/code/serenity/api/serenity-api/serenity/python/src/rbac/rbac.py
```

It's Python 2.7, running in a virtual env, if that matters.

Comment: *How* did you add to your `PYTHONPATH`? Depending on how you did it, you may have introduced some error that kept Python from seeing your desired directory.

Comment: @jjramsey The project is setup via a shell script that exports a bunch of variables before starting up gunicorn.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question. For example, if you modified your PYTHONPATH by prepending ~/foo to it, Python would not see ~/foo in your path because `~` isn't expanded to the location of your home directory; Python would just see a literal `~`. However, prepending "$HOME/foo" to `PYTHONPATH` in a shell script would work, since `$HOME` is expanded, unlike the `~`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to complicate It this much as to extending the path. In fact that is quite risky to do. If you know where the module is located just copy the module directory to the same directory where your source is located, after that you can just acces it like you have done in the code above.

Comment: That's not a scalable approach. While modifying `PYTHONPATH` can be dicey, what you suggest becomes impractical if, for example, one has to use the module in multiple sources in different directories. It's especially problematic if the module is large, composed of multiple files, etc.

Comment: You can still declare the path to the module, what I clearly suggest is that you don't mess up the Python path.

Answer (score 0):

The variable PYTHONPATH only survive in the process that you execute first, not exist in the process when you execute python `from rbac.rbac import Rbac` .

#### solution

you can do:
write shell script

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/code/serenity/api/serenity-api/serenity/python/src/
python -c "from rbac.rbac import Rbac"
```

and run it 
- Or write python script

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("~/code/serenity/api/serenity-api/serenity/python/src/")
from rbac.rbac import Rbac
```

and run it

Comment: Using "`~`" in place of `$HOME` probably won't work in this context. It didn't when I tested it out.